# iText PDF Stretch a character

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm using iText PDF 2.1.7 to create a PDF. Anyone has an idea if stretching the height of a single character (a closing curly brace, ASCII 125), is possible with iText PDF?

[image: Stretched closing curly brace]

The height of the stretched curly brace will depend on the height of the preceding cell's height. (Pardon my sample image, the upper curly brace should be taller than the lower curly brace.

If stretching the height of a single character is not possible, any other workaround you could suggest that still utilizes iText PDF library?

Thanks much.

---

[image: Curly brace]

I'm now using the iText version 5.4.0.

I'm having problem with scaling the height of the Image. Also, the Image is on the wrong position, though I copied the Cell's position. The bottom part of the curly brace is not displayed.

Do you know what is wrong with the way I scale the Image and on how I position it? Thanks.

```
public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
    PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
    try {

        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(
            CreatePDFCurlyBrace.DEFAULT_ENGLISH_FONT_TTF, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
            BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        String curlyBrace = "}";
        float width = bf.getWidthPoint(curlyBrace, 12);
        float height = bf.getAscentPoint(curlyBrace, 12)
            - bf.getDescentPoint(curlyBrace, 12);

        PdfTemplate template = this.cb.createTemplate(width, height);
        template.beginText();
        template.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
                    template.setTextMatrix(0, bf.getDescentPoint(curlyBrace, 12));
        template.showText(curlyBrace);
        template.endText();

        // Scale the image so that its height corresponds 
        //   with the height of the cell
        Image img = Image.getInstance(template);
        img.scaleToFit(1000f, position.getHeight());
        img.setAbsolutePosition(position.getRight(), position.getBottom());
                    cb.addImage(img);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the left part is a cell, and the right part is a cell, and the curly brace is kind of the "border" between the cells, I would define a cell event for either the left or the right cell.

I would create a simple `PdfTemplate` to which I'd add a curly brace. I'd base the dimensions of the PdfTemplate on the metrics information of the curly brace (ascender - descender = actual height). I wouldn't care about the font size; we just need a PdfTemplate object with a curly brace glyph.

I would wrap the `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image` object. Don't worry: this doesn't turn your "vector" template into a "raster" image. The `Image` object just makes it easier to manipulate the template.

I would implement the `cellLayout()` method in the cell event, and scale the image so that its height corresponds with the height of the cell (no loss of resolution: you've used a PdfTemplate, you're adding vector data, not a raster image), and add the image at the correct position (passed to the `cellLayout()` method using the `position` parameter).

It goes without saying that I wouldn't use iText 2.1.7 (a version which is 4 years old!) for this task, because I've fixed a bug a couple of years ago that caused `PdfPTable` to lose a row one in a million times. To avoid this bug, I wouldn't trick my customer into using an iText version that is considered obsolete: http://lowagie.com/itext2

Comment: Can you give me a sample code? What interface I should implement for the cellLayout() you've mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: There's plenty of sample code on http://itextpdf.com/book You need http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=201 and http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=149

Comment: Bruno, I followed your advice, however I encountered problems with scaling the **Image**. Kindly check my post containing the code. Thanks.